# Resize a TrueCrypt Partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, truecrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand TrueCrypt volume on Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/119594/expand-truecrypt-volume-on-mac-os)

How is it possible to resize a partition encrypted with TrueCrypt without corrupting the data ?

Comment: I did see that questions, however is volume == partition?

Comment: Please see this question:

http://superuser.com/questions/119594/expand-truecrypt-volume-on-mac-os

While the question is about Mac OS, the answers are valid for all platforms.

Comment: I did see that question, however is a volume the same thing as a partition?

Comment: "partition" and "volume" can have various meaning, but generally, **partition** refers to a physical section of the hard-drive; **volume** refers to a formatted filesystem or other logical data layout.  you can put a TrueCrypt volume or a formatted filesystem on either a physical partition or on a single file.  in your case, you need to expand the physical partition first, then use the answer from the other question to expand the TrueCrypt volume, then use Disk Management to expand the filesystem within the TrueCrypt volume.